# (how) can I install android on an iphone 4?

Tags: installation, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I know it is possible to [install Android on an iPhone 3G](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/571/installing-android-on-iphone-3g).

How about the iPhone 4? Is it possible to run Android on it? If yes, how, and what are the risks?
If no, is that a "not yet" or a "can't happen, because of X"?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say "not yet", at this moment.

My suggestion is to keep your eye on this page: http://www.idroidproject.org/wiki/Status

As you can see from the Wiki table on the iPhone4, the iDroid project participants aren't even sure exactly what hardware is in it yet. So writing code for it without that knowledge is a bit of a challenge.

Seeing as iDroid doesn't even run on iPhone 3GS, I would guess that it's gonna be a while before it runs on the iPhone4. Although, they do have it listed on the Wiki, so the iDroid devs are probably considering it at some point "down the road".

Answer (score 0):

I have it installed on my 3G, and it's just for scientific purposes. I just want to learn more about the filesystem and innerworkings of both OSes. To that end, I think it's very interesting. Not at all useful though. It crashes frequently, [I have not yet been able to connect to a WiFi network](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/1076/connect-to-wep-secured-mywi-network-from-iphodroid), and when it does run, it's kinda sluggish. But if you've got an *** EXTRA *** iPhone, I would say go for it.